# POSIX threads & semaphores

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore, producer-consumer

I'm not able to debug the following program, since I don't have linux at home. I can't execute the program, but while I was compiling the program in lab session, I got two errors. Can anyone help me out? If anyone is able to execute this program after debugging it, please do post the output, please.

The code is as follows :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
sem_t empty;
sem_t full;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

pthread_t ptid,ctid;
pthread_attr_t attr;

void *producer(void *param);
void *consumer(void *param);

int counter;
int main()
{

  init();
  pthread_create(&ptid, &attr, producer, NULL);
  pthread_create(&ctid, &attr, consumer, NULL);
  pthread_join(ptid,NULL);
  pthread_join(ctid,NULL);

  return 0;
}

void init()
{
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
  counter = 0;
  for(int j=0;j<BUFFER_SIZE;j++)
  {  buffer[j] = 0;}
}

void *producer(void *param)
{
int item;
  while(1)
  {
    item=item+1;
    sem_wait(&empty);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    if(insert_item(item))
    {
      perror("Producer error.");
      return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Producer produced %d\n", item);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&full);
  }
}

void *consumer(void *param)
{
  int item;
  while(1)
  {
sleep(5);
    sem_wait(&full);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if(remove_item(item))
    {
      perror( "Consumer error.");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Consumer consumed %d\n", item);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&empty);
  }
}
int insert_item(int item)
{
  if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE)
  {
    buffer[counter] = item;
    counter++;
    return 0;
  }
  else
    return -1;

}

int remove_item(int item)
{
  if(counter > 0)
  {
    item = buffer[(counter-1)];
    counter--;
    return ;
  }
  else
    return -1;

}
```

after making the changes and corrections im getting the following output now which is not the desired one.......

```
[root@localhost sree58]# gcc producerconsumer.c -lpthread -lrt
producerconsumer.c: In function ‘producer’:
producerconsumer.c:54: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
[root@localhost sree58]# ./a.out
Producer produced 1804289383
Producer produced 846930886
Producer produced 1681692777
Producer produced 1714636915
Producer produced 1957747793
Producer produced 424238335
Producer produced 719885386
Producer produced 1649760492
Producer produced 596516649
Producer produced 1189641421
Consumer error.: Success
Producer produced 1025202362
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 1350490027
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 783368690
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 1102520059
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 2044897763
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 1967513926
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 1365180540
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 1540383426
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 304089172
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 1303455736
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 35005211
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 521595368
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 294702567
Consumer error.: Illegal seek
Producer produced 1726956429
```

please someone guide me......

Comment: What errors?  I, for one, do not provide a free debugging service.

Comment: i know..... but pls help me...... im asking the help because i dont have linux at home.... and i have to submit this program tomorrow.... the errors are related to init() function i guess..... pls do help me....

Comment: Try using any of the freely available online IDE:s. They are quite likely to build in a Linux-like environment, I think.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [Oracle's VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)? It's a very simple application that lets you run a Linux box inside your windows machine, and it's free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i was compiling the program in lab session, i got two errors..... can
>   anyone help me out????

1) Remove for loop initial declaration in `for(int j=0;j<BUFFER_SIZE;j++);`, or compile with option `-std=c99`

2) Link with the pthread library.

```
gcc  main.c -lpthread
```

There were also a bunch of warnings , take care to fix them.

-- EDIT --

In your remove_item() , change return; to return 0;

Here is the output

```
Producer produced 4001537
Producer produced 4001538
Producer produced 4001539
Producer produced 4001540
Producer produced 4001541
Producer produced 4001542
Producer produced 4001543
Producer produced 4001544
Producer produced 4001545
Producer produced 4001546
Consumer consumed 4001536
Producer produced 4001547
Consumer consumed 4001536
Producer produced 4001548
Consumer consumed 4001536
Producer produced 4001549
Consumer consumed 4001536
Producer produced 4001550
Consumer consumed 4001536
Producer produced 4001551
Consumer consumed 4001536
Producer produced 4001552
Consumer consumed 4001536
Producer produced 4001553
Consumer consumed 4001536
Producer produced 4001554
Consumer consumed 4001536
Producer produced 4001555
Consumer consumed 4001536
;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: this ouptut is before fixing the error of return statement in removeitem function ....right????

Comment: no after fixing the return statement

Comment: ohhhk thanks..... that means still something is wrong with my program..... consumer is not consuming the item ..... right????

Comment: @chinu , am sorry the previous output was before fixing return , now i have posted the output after fixing it , your program works fine

Answer (score 6):

First, let's address this (the tools to help yourself): `since i don't have linux at home`

Go to Oracle's site and download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) then go to the site of your favorite Linux distro and download a `.iso` image of it (for example if you were feeling Minty you could go get a iso [here](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=119))

Then you can follow the instructions to set up and "install" the iso in the virtual machine and voila! You have Linux at home. ;)

Second, I'll address this: `i got two errors`

Really? How are you compiling this? I see a shload of warnings and 1 error when running your code with `gcc -Wall`. The one error tells you how to fix it in the message too:

```
38:3: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
38:3: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

Adding that command `gcc -Wall -std=c99` and now you see the undefined references due to the missing pthread library:

```
undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

Which is fixed by linking that in:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 <yourfile>.c -lpthread
```

---

Now all you have is a bunch of (important) warnings:

```
In function ‘main’:
22:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘init’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
At top level:
31:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘init’ [enabled by default]
22:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘init’ was here

In function ‘producer’:
51:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘insert_item’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
54:7: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

In function ‘consumer’:
71:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sleep’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
74:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘remove_item’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

In function ‘remove_item’:
106:5: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [enabled by default]

In function ‘consumer’:
74:19: warning: ‘item’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Comment: @chinu - you're welcome, and if you have any problems setting up VirtualBox you can ask on the [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) site.

Comment: i checked out for virtual box now...... but the site info says that i need to hav 64-bit configuration on my pc..... but i hav 32 bit configuration........

Comment: @chinu - not sure where you read that, but I know it works on both (there is a 32 bit and 64 bit exe in the install directory). Check out the [documentation for requirements on windows here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#installation_windows)

Comment: @chinu , in remove_item , do make the correction of return statement

Comment: @BarathBushan yaa.....sure i will....  thank yu...

Comment: @BarathBushan please can u tell me why im not getting the desired output after making the necessary changes.....

Comment: @Mike please can u tell me why im not getting the desired output after making the necessary changes..... i hav posted the output wihich im getting currently..... pls help me out

Comment: @chinu , what is your desired output ?? Is it the one i posted in my answer , or something else ?? If the output is the one i posted in my answer , here is the [code](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7C2FD17B2A9B9F4!1495) i used. Just compile it with `gcc prodcons.c -lpthread`.

Comment: @chinu - Your best bet at this point is to open a new question. Post your current program, your input and the output you're getting, as well as the output you expected. Then narrow down the problem a little yourself and ask others for help on a targeted area. Very few are willing to read an entire program so you should be able to narrow down the problem to one or two functions instead of "my program doesn't work". You should get a good response with that.

Comment: @Mike thanks alot for your advice...... but i came to know what mistake i did.......